# Create an array of function pointer in heap

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, heap-memory

I have an array of 6 function pointers:

```
int (*arrayOfFunPointers[6])();
```

What I want to do now, is to allocate that array in heap
Because I create the array in a function and return a pointer to that array:

```
int (*(*fun2())[6])(){

    int (*funPointer)();
    int (*arrayOfFunPointers[6])();
    int (*(*pointerToArrayOfFunPointers)[6])();

    funPointer = &fun;
    arrayOfFunPointers[0] = funPointer;
    pointerToArrayOfFunPointers = &arrayOfFunPointers;

    return pointerToArrayOfFunPointers;
}
```

Outside of the method, the `arrayOfFunPointers` lose his validity area and the returned pointer point to "nothing"

I tried a lot like:

```
int (*arrayOfFunPointers[6])() = new int (*[6])();
```

or with typedef:

```
typedef int (*arrayOfFunPointers[6])();
arrayOfFunPointerss *array = new arrayOfFunPointers;
```

or by assignment to the returned pointer:

```
pointerToArrayOfFunPointers = new arrayOfFunPointers;
pointerToArrayOfFunPointers = new arrayOfFunPointers[]; //or
```

But nothing works.
Maybe I do not understand the use of the keyword `new` correctly, then it would be very helpful if anyone could tell me where I make a thinking mistake

Can anyone help me please? That would be nice

Comment: Even if you succeed in getting a pointer to an array of pointers to functions (gasp!), any attempts to *call* one of those functions will look just horrible, perhaps `(*((*ptr)[i]))();`, so why bother? Go with YSC's simplification instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your life with tools from C++11. What about:

```
std::array<FunPointer, 6> getFunctions()
{
    std::array<FunPointer, 6> result;
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

isn't it just *nice*? Ne need to bother with dynamic memory, just copy those 6 pointers around, it is relatively cheap.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I will try it out. Is `FunPointer` a typedef?

Comment: It works, thanks. But the question was more: Can I do it and not can I simplify it. Please excuse if the question was inaccurate.